# kdb how to calculate rolling count

Tags: kdb

Assume I have a table of events, with Timestamp and Type.

```
t1, 'b'
t2, 'x'
t3, 's'
t4, 'b'
```

How can I get a rolling count such that it would give me a list of all timestamps and the cummulative number of events up to taht ts, sort of like a count version of sums

```
for example for 'b' I d like a table

't1', 1
't2', 1
't3', 1
't4', 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it, although there may be a more clever way this uses sums:

```
//table definition
tab:([]a:`t1`t2`t3`t4;b:"bxsb")

//rolling sum of 1 by column b
update sums count[i]#1 by b from tab
```

Results in:

```
a  b x
------
t1 b 1
t2 x 1
t3 s 1
t4 b 2
```

If you wanted replace b you would simply put `b:` in front of the `sums` .

Answer (score 1):

One way:

```
q)t:([]p:asc 4?.z.p+til 1000;t:`b`x`s`b)
q)asc `p xcols ungroup select p,til count i by t from t
p                             t x
---------------------------------
2017.05.16D09:42:48.259062090 b 0
2017.05.16D09:42:48.259062585 x 0
2017.05.16D09:42:48.259062683 s 0
2017.05.16D09:42:48.259062858 b 1
```

Ps: Note I have started the sequence at 0 as if to say "I've had 0 events prior to this row" instead of beginning at 1 as per your example. It goes with your req "number of events up to that ts". If you need 1, just add 1 '1+til count i'. Also ensure your time is sorted so as it makes sense when beginning the sequence.

Answer (score 1):

With table `t` as below:

```
q)show t: ([]ts:.z.t - desc "u"$(til 4);symb:`b`x`z`b)
ts           symb
-----------------
09:46:56.384 b
09:47:56.384 x
09:48:56.384 z
09:49:56.384 b
```

using a vector conditional:

```
q)select ts, cum_count:sums ?[symb=`b;1;0] from t
ts           cum_count
----------------------
09:46:56.384 1
09:47:56.384 1
09:48:56.384 1
09:49:56.384 2
```

The same, but with a function taking `symb` as a parameter:

```
q){select ts, cum_count:sums ?[symb=x;1;0] from t}[`b]
ts           cum_count
----------------------
09:46:56.384 1
09:47:56.384 1
09:48:56.384 1
09:49:56.384 2
```

In fact you don't need a vector conditional because you can just sum the booleans directly:

```
q){select ts, cum_count:sums symb=x from t}[`b]
ts           cum_count
----------------------
09:46:56.384 1
09:47:56.384 1
09:48:56.384 1
09:49:56.384 2
```

Answer (score 0):

This also works

update x:1+til count i by b from tab